# what does the symbol '$' mean in angular?

Tags: angular

What does mean by **$** in ${some_var}

```
search(term:string) {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20`;
        this.http.get(apiURL)
            .toPromise()
            .then(
            res => { // Success
                console.log(res.json());
                resolve();
                   }
                 );
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Thats [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to use for string interpolation.

Earlier we use below code for string concatenation

```
var user ="lokesh"

var testStr = "my name is "+ user
```

Now in typescript and in ECMA6 that can be used like this

```
var user ="lokesh"

var testStr = `my name is ${user}`
```

In your case 
 old version

```
 let apiURL = this.apiRoot + '?term='+term+'&media=music&limit=20';
```

typescript and ECMA6

```
 let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20`;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are other usage of $ sign:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async" >
```

in this case, The $ is a convention that indicates heroes$ is an Observable, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

${} are used as placeholders in a template string,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals